# Plot network graph by rolling period using R

Tags: r, igraph, rolling-computation

I was trying to conduct the network graph and some statistics by rolling three-year period, but I don't know how to set the rolling function. Below is my coding without rolling.

```
> library(igraph)
> em <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE )
> network <- graph.data.frame(em, directed = TRUE )
> em
   sender receiver weights year
1       a        d       2 2001
2       b        a       3 2001
3       c        a       1 2001
4       d        h       1 2001
5       e        d       3 2001
6       a        b       1 2002
7       b        c       2 2002
8       c        d       1 2002
9       d        a       1 2002
10      e        h       2 2002
11      a        d       1 2003
12      b        d       1 2003
13      c        a       2 2003
14      d        h       2 2003
15      e        a       1 2003
16      a        d       1 2004
17      b        c       1 2004
18      c        d       2 2004
19      d        c       1 2004
20      e        a       2 2004
> E(network)$weight <- as.numeric(network[,3])
Warning message:
In eattrs[[name]][index] <- value :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> p <- plot (network,edge.width=E(network)$weight)
```

So in this example eventually it would come up with one weighed network graph. I would like to conduct the graphs using data in 2001-2003 and 2002-2004 subsamples, further with some SNA statistics. Some online resource suggests -rollappy()- or the functions in package -tidyquant- could do, but I didn't manage to figure our how to recognise the 4th column as year and how to set the rolling period. Would much appreciate it if anyone can help out, as I am a newbie to R.

Many thanks!!

Comment: A few things: 1) `network[,3]` is not correct I'm not even sure what it is referencing. what what you meant to do is `em[,3]`, but in fact this is already stored here: `E(network)$weights`. 2) What exactly are you trying to roll together? And what operation do you want to perform" A sum of the weight for 2001-2003? Something else? 3) You can subset your graph using the following form: `g1 <- delete_edges(network, which(E(network)$year %in% c(2004)))`

Comment: @emilliman5 Hi! Thx for the questions. I posted the further code below now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @emilliman5 for the further questions.

My real dataset is an unbalanced panel with 15-year time span. I was intended to conduct network graphs using part of the full data. Subtracting rule is the 3-year rolling period (in fact with some other conditions but I just asked rolling here). So I planned to call the rolling subsamples first and conduct graphs. I hope it is a bit clear now.

Above data was just a mock sample. 4-year range should generate two graphs (2001-2003, 2002-2004), and 15-year should come up with 13 graphs. The real weighting variable is not called weight, but I agree the line "as.numeric(network[,3])" is redundant. (I realise now the example I made wasn't good...sorry...)

I get someone helped me with that now, so I'll just post some of the codes. Hope it might help other people.

Method 1: call sub-samples by function. This save me from constructing the nested loops together with graphing.

```
# Function: conditions for substracting; here rolling-year only
f <- function(j){                 
df <- subset(em, year>=j & year <= j+2)
}

print (f(2001))                  # Test function output, print-out

# Rolling by location and year, graph-plotting
for (j in 2001:2002){
sdf = f(j)                              
nw <- graph.data.frame(sdf, directed = TRUE)
plot(nw, edge.width = E(sdf[[j]])$weight)
}
```

Method 2: Use loops -- fine for one or two subtracting conditions but would be a bit clumsy for more.

```
c <- 2001                       # a number for year count
sdf <- {}                       # Set an empty set to save subsets
for (j in 2001:2002){
df_temp <- subset(em, year>=j & year<=j+2)
print(nrow(df_temp))            # To check the subset, not necessary
sdf[[c]] <- cbind(df_temp)
nw <- graph.data.frame(sdf[[c]], directed = TRUE)
plot(nw, edge.width = E(sdf[[c]])$weight)
c <- c + 1
}
```